# How do I get the default background color in ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using the `ActionBar` from the `ActionBarSherlock` library. I am able to set the background color of my action bar using the `ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(Color)` method. After changing the background color, I later need to revert it back to the original/default `ActionBar` color.

How can I determine what the original/default color used for the `ActionBar` was?

Comment: More importantly, are you quite certain that you can change the `ActionBarSherlock`s background `Drawable` multiple times? I never had much luck with this (from vague memory, I think that subsequent calls to `.setBackgroundDrawable()` had no effect when I tried). In the end I just got fed up with faffing about and resorted to doing any clever background colour stuff for the `ActionBar` by just shoving a `View` behind it.

Comment: Trevor, I've done a test and I am able to change the backgound colour multiple times.

Comment: Ah, in that case I'll get back into my box. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the theme you are using. It should be

- `R.drawable.abs__ab_transparent_dark_holo` for `Theme.Sherlock`
- `R.drawable.abs__ab_solid_light_holo` for `Theme.Sherlock.Light`
- `R.drawable.abs__ab_solid_dark_holo` for `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Matthias. Do you know if there's any way I can determine in code what theme is being used?

Comment: You may find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267852/android-how-to-obtain-the-resource-id-of-the-current-theme

Answer (score -1):

Don't just Create a Model class that will remember what you are setting, and you be able to roll back when ever you wish.

Comment: The first setting of the background colour is done by the library. That is the colour I am after.