# Get the Theme value applied for an activity programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-styles

I want to know which theme is applied for an Activity in an application.

Normally we are setting the theme by using

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
```

Here we are specifying style, As like this can we able to get the specific style type exactly applied for an activity programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Context class has a nice method called `getThemeResId`, however it's private thus you need to use reflection.

Here's an example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Log.e("TAG", "Def theme: " + R.style.AppTheme);
    Log.e("TAG", "Light theme: " + android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    Log.e("TAG", "Current theme id: " + getThemeId());

    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    Log.e("TAG", "Current theme id: " + getThemeId());
}

int getThemeId() {
    try {
        Class<?> wrapper = Context.class;
        Method method = wrapper.getMethod("getThemeResId");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (Integer) method.invoke(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems it's not working now.. at least in kotlin.

Comment: This uses reflection to access a private API. This solution is not reliable as the private API can change anytime, therefore it could break your app.