# Detect the Android device theme (is it dark or light)

Tags: android, android-theme

You can set the theme for your app, but I'm wondering if it's possible to find out which one is used by the device. Currently, my app uses `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. I'd like to avoid changing the theme.

P.S. I've already tried to set it to `Theme.DeviceDefault` and access its ID using reflection, but no luck so far.

```
try {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);

    Class<Context> contextClass = Context.class;
    Method getThemeMethod = contextClass.getMethod("getThemeResId");
    getThemeMethod.setAccessible(true);
    Log.d("Test", "" + getThemeMethod.invoke(this)); // Always returns 0

    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Log.d("Test", getResources().getResourceEntryName(packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme)); // Returns 'Theme.DeviceDefault'
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Test", "exception", e);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking, how to use the device set theme?

Comment: basically theme selected by your IDE.If you want to avoid u can change theme.

Comment: @Doomsknight No, I don't want to use the device default theme. I'd like to tell if this theme is dark or light.

Comment: The theme you are using has `.Light` in the name, surely it is light.

Comment: @Doomsknight You got me wrong. I want to know if the OS theme is light or dark. I don't need to change my app theme.

Comment: Woops. your last two sentences are confusing as they bear no relevance to the question. I was wondering how the avoid changing theme came in, and thought you were meaning something else.

Comment: @Doomsknight I added this to emphasize I want to keep my app theme unchanged.

Comment: @Doomsknight I saw some answers suggesting to replace it with `Theme.DeviceDefault`. Unfortunately, that's not an option for me.

Comment: @Nikolai did you find an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
int currentNightMode = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;  
switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active on device
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active on device
        break;
}
```

Comment: I believe he is asking for the theme used by the OS system, not the app itself.

Comment: Based on his comments on the question, He wants to know the device theme is light or dark.

Comment: device or OS system, same thing, but not the app

Comment: This will check for the device theme. Sorry for the misinformation in the comment.

Comment: For the Kotlin solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57685102/6411857

Answer (score 1):

This might help [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to apply the device theme. I've already seen this suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26302184/3185295

Comment: So you just want to know which theme is device using currently?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: U can use getTheme() method

Comment: getTheme() would return my app theme. But I need to retrieve the device theme.