# How can I detect programmatically if the Android Device is in Dark Mode?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, android-dark-theme

I'm trying to support the Android Q Dark theme for my Android app and I can't figure out how to import different assets based on the theme I'm currently in.

Im using the official DayNight theme for making the dark/light versions and for drawables is very easy to just point to the XML and it will choose the correct value either from values or values-night depending on what is enabled.

I wanted to do something similar where depending on the theme it would load either the asset "priceTag_light.png" or "priceTag_dark.png".

```
val inputStream = if(darkIsEnabled) { 
                    assets.open("priceTag_dark.png")
                  } else {
                    assets.open("priceTag_light.png")
                  }
```

Is there a way I get that flag?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay finally found the solution I was looking for. As [@deepak-s-gavkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2446911/deepak-s-gavkar) points out the parameter that gives us that information is on the Configuration. So, after a small search I found [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-dark-theme-implementation-recap-4fcffb0c4bff) article that gives this example method that has worked perfectly for what I wanted:

```
fun isDarkTheme(activity: Activity): Boolean {
        return activity.resources.configuration.uiMode and
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
    }
```

Comment: You can also use `Context` instead of `Activity` to make it easier to use :·)

Comment: fun Context.isDarkTheme(): Boolean {
        return resources.configuration.uiMode and
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
    }

Comment: How could you tell if the dark mode setting of the Application is set to "follow system"?

Answer (score 7):

You first need to do this changes in manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="uiMode" />
```

then onConfigurationChanged of activity

```
val currentNightMode = resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
when (currentNightMode) {
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {} // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {} // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
}
```

Comment: He wants to know whether dark mode is enabled or not which is feature of Android Q.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I wanted since I wanted to check during start time, not when a change was produced. But it pointed me in the right direction and found what I was looking. Thank you!

Comment: Why it is needed to set uiMode to configChanges?

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code:

```
boolean isDarkThemeOn = (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)  == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
```