# How to determine system's current day-night theme in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-night-mode

I am using this theme for my app:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
```

And When I change my phone's day-night mode from settings my app is changing too. But I also need to change the color of the text of the status bar.

**Question:**
How to determine the system's theme?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57686965/13083841

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MahdiM. It has really worked!!! I was searching for that answer.