# How to check if dark theme exists in Android OS?

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

Officially [dark theme is available in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme), but in reality, dark theme available in Android 9 MIUI 11 for example. Is there a way to check programmatically if OS dark theme available or not? I tried to check it through the [`Configuration#uiMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#uiMode) field:

```java
public boolean isSystemDarkAllowed() {
    final Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    final int nightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    return nightMode != Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED;
}
```

but it is not working, for Android 5 it returns `true`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357331/detect-the-android-device-theme-is-it-dark-or-light

Comment: @Nik No, I know, how to detect the theme (night or dark). I need an answer how to detekt OS possibility for dark theme

Answer (score 0):

yes you can check this by below code

```
  switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
       case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
           Log.v("BaseActivity","THEME_DARK");
           break;
       case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
          Log.v("BaseActivity","THEME_LIGHT");
          break;
```

**Edit**

i have added theam as below by using below code.

```
  switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            Log.v("BaseActivity","THEME_DARK");
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dark);
            Consts.currentTheme=Consts.THEME_DARK;
            break;
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            Log.v("BaseActivity","THEME_LIGHT");
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            Consts.currentTheme=Consts.THEME_LIGHT;
            break;
```

Comment: No no, I know it, but I need to know about OS dark theme possibility. For example for Android 10 it is available by default, some devices with Android 9 accept it too, but all devices with android kitkat can not setup dark theme on all OS UI