# Android isDarkTheme() and isLightTheme()

Tags: android, android-view, android-theme

I'm developing an Android library that `extends android.view.View`. The library must adapt the theme choosen by developer whether it is `DarkTheme` or `LightTheme`. For example in `LightTheme`, the `TextView` color is black, on the contrary in `DarkTheme` the `TextView` color is white.

The problem is how to detect the theme choosen by developer? Is it dark or light? Is there any function like `AppTheme instanceof DarkTheme`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question has been already answered there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301345/get-the-theme-value-applied-for-an-activity-programmatically .

Answer (score 0):

The following method gives you theme name. From this theme name you can find whether it is a light theme or dark theme.

```
public String getThemeName(Context context){
   PackageInfo packageInfo;
   try{
    packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    int themeResId = packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme;
    return getResources().getResourceEntryName(themeResId);
   }
   catch (NameNotFoundException e){
    return null;
   }
}
```